# non-recursive read write lock in Java

Tags: java, synchronization, locking

Is there an implementation of a multiple-reader-single-writer lock in Java which is non-recursive? The closest I could find is the [ReentrantReadWriteLock](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantReadWriteLock.html), but it's recursive which is not what I'm looking for.

Comment: You mean re-entrant.

Comment: @EJP Oddly, the documentation says "recursive" too.  "This lock supports a maximum of 65535 recursive write locks and 65535 read locks"